# How to transfer files from an amazon EC2 linux vps to a windows 7 home pc

Tags: linux, ftp, amazon-ec2, vps, public-key

Ok i have spent atleast a week trying to get this solved, looked all over and I see alot of solutions... Problem is none of them work for me. I have a linux EC2 instance from amazon.com. I want to move some files from that vps to my computer... I am currently connecting to it from Putty but i have tried Filezilla and alot of other things like that. When I use the command

`scp root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/home/ec2-user/filefolder/folder-i-want-to-transfer C:/`

I get the following:

```
The authenticity of host 'ip-xx-xx-xx-xx (xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ip-xx-xx-xx-xx,xx.xx.xx.xx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please help if you could.

Comment: I think your EC2 instance only allow key login, is it right? Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config, is "PasswordAuthentication yes" enabled?

Comment: Also, same in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, is "PermitRootLogin" enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems:

1. You've disabled root logins via ssh.
2. You're using a key that you don't want to.

I won't tell you how to solve the first; create another user account and transfer the files via that account instead.

For the second, you need to tell your tool to not use any key whatsoever.

```
scp -i NUL: ...
scp -i /dev/null ...
```

You should then be able to log in using the account's password.

Comment: Not sure that helped at all :( I entered the commands as written and got the following:"usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
[ec2-user@ip-10-56-71-10 ~]$ scp -i /dev/null
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
" also i can sudo su to get root permission

Comment: logging in as root@myamazonawsip.com is not allowed by default... I do not know how to change any of these, and believe me i have searched for it over and over again. The account is ec2-user by default for all ec2 users and there is no password... when i want to connect via putty i simply put my "mykey.ppk" into the settings under "auth" and in hotname/ipadress i type in ec2-user@myamazonawsip.com and im in.

Comment: You're not supposed to enter the commands as written; you're supposed to add `-i` and its argument to your existing command(s).